# Webpack Hot Module Replacement not working for every file

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, redux, webpack-dev-server

My application uses hot module replacement but for some reason
it is not working for some directories.

Ive noticed that if i change file A "webpack building..." appears 
and HMR ist working.

But for other files it does not appear.

It is a react/redux/express application with typescript (should not be important)

FileA and FileB are both redux containers (pages). The routes are working and i can see the content.

Here is my directory.

```
- src
|  - containers
|    |
|    |- Account
|    |  |
|    |--- FileB (not working)
|    
|  - FileA (working
```

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of testing and searching i found that my file was named
lower case but my export was uppercase.

Source: [HMR not working when component is inside the subdirectory](https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-boilerplate/issues/86)